# Show all xlabels and xticks in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot multiple figures on a single pane using `matplotlib.pyplot`'s `subplot`. Here is my current code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2], "col2": [3,4], "col3": [5,6], "col4": [7,8], "target": [9,10]})

f, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, sharey = True)

# for ax in axs.flat:
#     ax.label_outer()

for k, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if col != "target":
        idx = np.unravel_index(k, (2,2))
        axs[idx].scatter(df[col], df.target)
        axs[idx].set_xlabel(col)
```

As it stands, with the two lines commented out, this prints all the `xticks` but only the `xlabels` for the bottom two plots.

[image]

If I uncomment those two lines, then the all the `xlabels` appear, but the `xticks` on the top row disappear. I think this is because the space has been 'freed up' by the `[label_outer][2]` function

[image]

I don't see how I can have both on the top row. If one prints out all the `xlabels`, then they are indeed all there.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call `plt.tight_layout()` after your loop. Refer to [the guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html) to know more about options and capabilities.

[image: Tight layout]

Comment: Thanks very much! I spent ages looking for this, but couldn't find it `:(`

Comment: Now, you know if you have a problem of layout, use `tight_layout` :-)

Comment: Yes! Indeed. It seems very counter-intuitive that _tight_ layout should allow for _more_ text to be shown. I'll certainly be referring to that guide in the future!